# Facebook permission error occurs even though I have it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I try to call the Facebook graph API to get public page pictures.
I have the "Advanced_access" for pages_read_engagement and pages_show_list in my Control App.

But when I call the page : [https://graph.facebook.com/my_page/photos?access_token={token_app}](https://graph.facebook.com/my_page/photos?access_token=%7Btoken_app%7D)

I have this error :

```
(#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' or 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature.
```

Thinking that my token wasn't up to date, I tried to call : [https://graph.facebook.com/my_page/photos?access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}](https://graph.facebook.com/my_page/photos?access_token=%7Bapp_id%7D%7C%7Bapp_secret%7D)

Same result. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: And `{token_app}` is what now, _exactly_?

Comment: @CBroe Now is : 1106618303054527|mnhmOsOV2I1J6rkwVGuo_uUnGQo. Why does not work with {app_id}|{app_secret} too ?

Comment: Because those are both _app_ access tokens, and you can not use those to perform actions in the name of a page.

Comment: P.s., I only wanted to know what _type_ of token you are using, not that you post an actual one. The one you have shown is still valid, so I am assuming that is based on your app secret to begin with - in which case, you should go and reset your app secret now, otherwise anyone here who’s read this now has a valid app access token for your app.

Comment: @CBroe Yes I will generate another thks. Then, what kind of token can perform on my page ? And how can I generate it ? This kind of token worked somes years ago

Comment: What kind of token the request needs, should be on the documentation page of the endpoint you are using there. And information about tokens in general, can be found under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens